# Assigning values of Two DB Columns to a Cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have a query that returns 2 set of Columns from DB and I want to how can I assign these columns to a Cursor and later use them for further processing.

Thats my Query:

```
 public  List<String> getAllCapabilities1(String myRub)             
                {

                    List<String> Caps = new ArrayList<String>();

                    // Select All Query
                    String selectQuery = "SELECT Cap_Name, Cap_ID FROM capability where Rub_ID = '"+myRub+"'";

                    SQLiteDatabase database = this.dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                    // looping through all rows and adding to list
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
                    {
                        do 
                        {
                          Caps.add(cursor.getString(0));
                        } 
                        while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
```

This query returns:

```
Cap_Name    Cap_ID
Cap 1         1
Cap 2         2   
Cap 3         3
```

With normal cursor I can handle one Column very easily but I need to know how to assign both columns at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Cursor is the ResultSet of SELECT query and it can contain any number of columns.

Each column value can be got as:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME", null);

while(c.moveToNext()) {
    Log.d("Column1", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Column1")));
    Log.d("Column2", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Column2")));
}
```

For your problem, create a custom class CapDetails with attributes CapId and CapName.

Change your method declaration as:

```
    public  List<CapDetails> getAllCapabilities1(String myRub)
```

and change the declaration caps to List of CapDetails instead of List of String.

within cursor loop:

```
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
                {
                   CapDetails capDetails = new CapDetails();

                   // Assign each column value to respective capDetails attribute. then,
                   caps.add(capDetails);
                }
```

Comment: I have added my query set so can you please have a look and point out the mistake? 
Thanks.